# How to configure mongodb with nodered on bluemix?

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud, node-red

I need to store data on bluemix using nodered, but i do not know how to set the condfiguration of the mongodb node?. I searched the internet and i find that there were a service called "mongolab" that you should add to your organization to be able to use monogodb, but i searched the mongolab service and i did not find it. Is there a way to configure and use mongodb on nodered?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the mongoDb service from Compose: https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/compose-for-mongodb

See these articles for how the integration would work with Compose and Mongodb:
https://www.compose.com/articles/power-prototyping-with-mongodb-and-node-red-2/
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/16740/node-red-and-mongodb.html

Here's the content from the link:

```
there's a good demo video involving MongoDB here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5o4tIz2Zzc

This uses twitter as the source of data to be in put into, and queried from, mongodb, but the principles are the same.

To answer some of your specific questions:

    you can use either save or insert for the case you describe. (This page describes the detailed difference
    you can pick your own collection name. You can have multiple collections within the database instance you have provisioned.
    the mongodb query node can be used to get the data back. The demo video above shows a quick and easy way to get to the data via an http request.
```

Comment: Please add more detail to this answer because as it is it is basically a link only answer and as such will become useless as soon as the links break

Comment: Yeah, i get that. But these are official links from the product website or articles describing how to solve the issue. Copied some of the content in here for posterity.